# Sails.js ORM Table Creation

Tags: orm, sails.js, blueprint

I'd like to ask, I had assumed that I do not have to use any table creation queries manually since there is an ORM.

Every time I try to connect to MYSQL it says that there is not a table like User as my controller's name. How can I automatize this process as ORM supposed to do?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Is there any property of sails I don't know to generate these tables?

Comment: In your config/models.js : http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html . I think you are in migrate: 'safe'.